# Criar WebAPI sem a estrutura do MVC é possível?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

O titulo da pergunta por si só define a minha dúvida, utilizando o VS2015, para criar uma API, ele me obriga a criar toda a estrutura do MVC junto. Então gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de criar a API somente com a estrutura do WebAPI no VS2015?

Comment: Tem certeza que te obriga? Você desmarcou a opção de MVC? Veja: http://media-www-asp.azureedge.net/media/4410055/getstarted02.png você uso o que quiser

Comment: então a opção do azure permite, porem a opção webapi, fica marcada com o mvc e nao me permite desmarcar queria entender essa diferença entre um e outro @bigown

Answer (score 1):

> [...] utilizando o VS2015, para criar uma API, ele me obriga a criar toda a estrutura do MVC junto.

Não, ele não te obriga a isso. O que acontece é que você está criando um projeto que **já tem uma estrutura básica** definida (template, em outras palavras). O checkbox **MVC** fica marcado porque este template usa a estrutura MVC, mas isso não quer dizer que você precise usá-lo.

> Então gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de criar a API somente com a estrutura do WebAPI no VS2015?

**Sim**, existe. Ao invés de escolher o template **WebApi** ao clicar em novo projeto ASP.NET, selecione o **Empty** e marque o checkbox **WebApi**. Todas as dependências necessárias serão baixadas e nenhuma dependência **MVC** será adicionada.

[image: Escolher tipo do projeto]

Veja as dependências que foram adicionadas

[image: Dependências instaladas]

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim.

O Visual Studio tem um template em New -> web site -> ASP.NET Web Service.

Não é necessário usar o padrão MVC para tal, apesar de ser uma boa recomendação.

No primeiro link tem um tutorial passo a passo caso queira:
[Web Service C#](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=web%20service%20C%23)